# Bash script - create number based on short string

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick

I'm using a bash script to drive ImageMagick to create images based on some inputs. One input is a short string called ${Episode_Number} which will either be two digits like "16" or two digits and a letter, like "16a". Based on this string, I want to produce a number from 0-255. (This will be the Hue in a Hue-Saturation-Brightness colour code.)

What is the best way to produce a number from a string like that? Any method is fine, as long as it produces the same colour from the same string every time.

I tried the $(( Episode_Number % 255 )) method but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: With two digits and a letter (00a-99z), you can produce 2600 codes, way too many to fit in your 0-255 range.  What will be the actual range of numbers and letters?

Comment: The (podcast) episode number will increment, and the (podcast cover art background) color must change each time. I don't see it going over 99.

Comment: See my response to your answer below. Sorry for being a bit vague, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This function will handle show numbers from 01 to 31g:

```
tonum() {
    a=${1,,}
    n=${a:0:2}
    [ "${#a}" -eq 3 ] && ((n+=32*($(printf "%d" "'${a:2}") - 96)))
    echo $n
}
```

Examples:

```
$ tonum 01
1
$ tonum 01a
33
$ tonum 31g
255
```

Show numbers 00 to 31 are assigned to values 0 to 31.  Show numbers 00a to 31a are assigned to 32 to 63. 00b to 31b are assigned to 64 to 95.  And so on.

#### How it works

- `a=${1,,}`

  This converts the function's first argument to lower case and assigns it to variable `a`.  This makes the function case-insensitive.
- `((n=${a:0:2}))`

  This takes the first two characters of `a` and assigns them to variable `n`.
- `[ "${#a}" -eq 3 ] && ((n+=32*($(printf "%d" "'${a:2}") - 96)))`

  If variable `a` has three characters, this converts the third character to a number, multiplies it by 32, and adds the result it to `n`.

  This uses a feature of `printf` that converts letters to numbers.  For example:

  ```
  $ printf "%d" "'a"
  97
  ```

  Lower case `a` becomes 97.  Lower case `b` becomes 98 and so on.  We subtract 96 from this so that `a` becomes 1.  Then, we multiply this by 32 to obtain the number that we want to add to `n`.
- `echo $n`

  This displays the result to stdout.

#### bash 3.x (Mac OSX)

The `,,` trick to convert a string to lower case requires bash 4.0 or better.  For platforms with older versions of bash, we can do the same with `tr`:

```
tonum() {
     a=$(echo "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
     n=${a:0:2}
     [ "${#a}" -eq 3 ] && ((n+=32*($(printf "%d" "'${a:2}") - 96)))
     echo $n
}
```

Comment: what version of bash is needed for `${1,,}` ?

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ Good point.  That requires 4.0 or better which leaves out Mac OSX.  I added to the answer a version which works with older versions of bash.

Comment: Thank you @John1024, that looks good. I will have to try this later on today.
To make this clearer: the (podcast) episode number will increment, and the (podcast cover art background) color must change each time. I don't see it going over 99. The ability to manage three-character values is more of a nice-to-have. The more likely scenario is the episode number will simply increment each time. 16, 17, 18 etc. But I think it would be nice to have the color change a significant amount each time - episode 17 should be a completely different color from 16.

Comment: As for the letters, to clarify, they may not be required. I included them as a nice-to-have, in case I did in-between mini-episodes.

Comment: @muteboy  _"I think it would be nice to have the color change a significant amount each time - episode 17 should be a completely different color from 16"_  With 99 episodes and only 256 possible values, there are serious limits.  With episodes incrementing by 2, that would cover 0 to 198.  We could have it wrap around a few times to that adjacent episode numbers would differ significantly but but distant episodes might have similar colors.  Given the issues of fitting 99 episodes fitting into 256 numbers, think seriously about what it is that you really want and then let me know.

Comment: @John2014, you're right, I do need to figure out what exactly I want. I guess I needed to figure out what was possible and how to achieve it. I appreciate your help. I'll play around with the solutions you've given me and see what I come up with. Best regards.

Comment: I know you were all dying to know how this ended, here's what I did. I took @John1024's idea of wrapping the result around so they differ sufficiently from one episode to the next. I also switched from HSB to HSL, and I've discarded the idea of episode "16a" etc. It's just a simple increment. With the Saturation at 60% and Lightness at 40% to give rich dark background colours for white overlay text, the Hue is calculated as
`modulus of (episode number * 99) / 360`
99 gives a nice jump in hue without being too regular, mod keeps it within 360. Simple once I decided exactly what I wanted!